# online reports for vb.net desktop application

Tags: vb.net, postgresql, report

I am developing a desktop application but would like users to be able to log in to my website to view reports generated from their data which is stored in a local PostgreSQL database. I am trying to figure out my options and if it is going to be possible to do this. It seems it would be a security risk/too much effort on the users end to open up their firewall ports in order to access their database from the internet. Another option is to create a 'reports' database on my website that my application could periodically update vital stats to which could then be used to create reports. I also could just create a .pdf in the application and upload that to the website to be viewed. This might be the easiest route. Are there any better/easier options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the solutions you have presented, the second solution seems sound.

A rough plan would be to:

- Have a feature in your webpage that Calls for the application in your server to generate the .pdf file
- Upload the Pdf to your webpage
- finally, send the file to the user for download.